# Обновление приложения в AppStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

Ситуация следующая: в *app store* уже есть приложение, его надо обновить. В сети очень много гайдов как залить приложение в *app store*, но я не нашел ни одного, как обновить приложение.
Если кто-то владеет подобной информацией, прделитесь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да все просто, заходите в itunesconnect -> мои приложения -> ваше приложение. Потом добавляете версию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

, после чего загружаете новый билд (только версия должна быть выше чем та что уже загружена, например если уже выпущена **1**.0.4, то вам нужно будет залить билд с версией **2**.0.0 .Последние 2 цифры на ваше усмотрение). Так же вы можете изменить отображаемое имя версии в itunesconnect (например билд будет 2.0.0 , но юзер увидит обновление 1.1.0) Дальше все как при выпуске приложения.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: я бы еще выкатывал обновления только после теста через TestFlight или Fabric (ну или любой другой сервис), мало-ли что может пойти не так после обновления